# Code copied from jsfiddle.net is not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to write a simple web page that accepts a parameter of a file URL and displays it but has a button that will turn the image 90 degrees with each click.  Here is the [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/JkHqa/) code that works like a charm for the turning part.  I have yet to add the passing in the file URL part but I can't get this to work despite copying it from jsfiddle.  I must be missing a library or something with the syntax.

Here is the html file, what did i miss?  I have tried different libraries and versions of jquery.  I'm not sure what to try next.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <img class="north"
    src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGPgQ8k88yaWVPRytT957hKLV-89QmZtkZc44q45TEDdqe9sKwqg">
  <input type="button" value="click me">
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .north {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
  }

  .west {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
  }

  .south {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */

  }

  .east {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
  }
</style>

<!-- Script -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
  $('input').click(function () {
    var img = $('img');
    if (img.hasClass('north')) {
      img.attr('class', 'west');
    } else if (img.hasClass('west')) {
      img.attr('class', 'south');
    } else if (img.hasClass('south')) {
      img.attr('class', 'east');
    } else if (img.hasClass('east')) {
      img.attr('class', 'north');
    }
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: *I must be missing a library or something with the syntax.* <-- Yes, you haven't imported JQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem concerns your last "script" tag, you must specify [the "src" or
the content between the tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src), but never both. So if we remove the "src" attribute, it'll work as expected.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <img class="north"
    src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGPgQ8k88yaWVPRytT957hKLV-89QmZtkZc44q45TEDdqe9sKwqg">
  <input type="button" value="click me">
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .north {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
  }

  .west {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
  }

  .south {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */

  }

  .east {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    /* Safari and Chrome */
  }
</style>

<!-- Script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('input').click(function () {
    var img = $('img');
    if (img.hasClass('north')) {
      img.attr('class', 'west');
    } else if (img.hasClass('west')) {
      img.attr('class', 'south');
    } else if (img.hasClass('south')) {
      img.attr('class', 'east');
    } else if (img.hasClass('east')) {
      img.attr('class', 'north');
    }
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the type attribute.